# unable to show anything on x-axis and y-axis labels in core-plot

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, core-plot

I'm using core plot in an application and from past one week I am trying to show labels on x-axis and y-axis. But haven't succeed yet. I'm posting my code here with screen shot. If someone knows any solution to fix the problem let me know urgently.

Code -

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Initialize all graph dependent data.
//self.dataForPlot = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

minYValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
maxYValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

[self createGraph];
[self customizeGraph];
   }

- (void) createGraph{

// Create graph
graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

CPGraphHostingView *hostingView = (CPGraphHostingView *)self.view;
hostingView.collapsesLayers = YES;
hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;
hostingView.frame = self.view.frame;

//Create a blue plot area
CPScatterPlot *boundLinePlot = [[[CPScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
boundLinePlot.dataLineStyle.miterLimit = 1.0f;
boundLinePlot.dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;

UIColor* color = [UIColor orangeColor];
boundLinePlot.dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor colorWithCGColor:[color CGColor]];
boundLinePlot.dataSource = self;
[graph addPlot:boundLinePlot];  
    }

  - (void) customizeGraph{
if(graph)
{

    graph.paddingLeft = 20.0;
    graph.paddingTop = 20.0;
    graph.paddingRight = 20.0;
    graph.paddingBottom = 20.0;




    CPScatterPlot *goalWeightPlot = [[[CPScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
    goalWeightPlot.identifier = kGoalWeightPlot;
        //boundLinePlot.dataLineStyle.miterLimit = 5.0f;
    goalWeightPlot.dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    goalWeightPlot.dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor redColor];
    goalWeightPlot.dataLineStyle.dashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0],nil];
    goalWeightPlot.dataSource = self;
    [graph addPlot:goalWeightPlot];


    // Create a blue plot area
    CPScatterPlot *boundLinePlot = [[[CPScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
    boundLinePlot.identifier = kActualWeightPlot;
        //boundLinePlot.dataLineStyle.miterLimit = 5.0f;
    boundLinePlot.dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    boundLinePlot.dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor orangeColor];
    boundLinePlot.dataSource = self;


    // Add plot symbols
    CPLineStyle *symbolLineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
    symbolLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor orangeColor];

    CPPlotSymbol *plotSymbol = [CPPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    plotSymbol.fill = [CPFill fillWithColor:[CPColor orangeColor]];
    plotSymbol.lineStyle = symbolLineStyle;
    plotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0);
    boundLinePlot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;
    [graph addPlot:boundLinePlot];
}
  }


  - (void) resetData{
  dataForPlot = nil;
  }

     - (void) setGraphData:(NSArray*)graphData andRefrenceValue:(float)goalValue{

self.refereceValue = goalValue;
[self setGraphData:graphData];

    }

    - (void) setGraphData:(NSArray*)graphData{

//Check if we have any single weight entry in the array
if(graphData && [graphData count] > 0) {
    [self prepareGraphData:graphData];
    [self setRangeForGraph];
    [graph reloadData];
 }
    }

- (NSArray *)sortedWeightEntriesByWeightDate:(NSArray *)unsortedArray {

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i=0;i<[unsortedArray count];i++) {

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    WeightEntry *entry = [unsortedArray objectAtIndex:i];

    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:entry.weightDate];

     NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    if(date) {      

        [dict setObject:entry forKey:@"entity"];

        [dict setObject:date forKey:@"date"];

        [tempArray addObject:dict];
    }

    [df release];
}

NSInteger counter = [tempArray count];

NSDate *compareDate;

NSInteger index;

for(int i = 0 ; i < counter; i++) {

    index = i;

    compareDate = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"date"];

    NSDate *compareDateSecond;

    for(int j = i+1 ; j < counter; j++)
    {
        compareDateSecond=[[tempArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"date"];

        NSComparisonResult result = [compareDate compare:compareDateSecond];
        if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
        {
            compareDate = compareDateSecond;
            index=j;
        }
    }
    if(i!=index)
        [tempArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:index];
}

NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
NSInteger counterIndex = [tempArray count];
for(int i = 0; i < counterIndex ; i++) {
    [sortedArray addObject:[[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"entity"]];
}
return [NSArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray];

 }


     - (void) prepareGraphData:(NSArray*)data{

data = [self sortedWeightEntriesByWeightDate:data];

NSNumber* minYValue = nil;
NSNumber* maxYValue = nil;


NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[data count]];
NSUInteger i;
for ( i = 0; i < [data count]; i++ ) {
    WeightEntry* weightEntry = [data objectAtIndex:i];

    if(i == 0){     
        maxYValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:weightEntry.weight];
        minYValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:weightEntry.weight];
    }

    //id x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:weightEntry.weight];
    //id y = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.2*rand()/(float)RAND_MAX + 1.2];

    id x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:i];
    id y = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:weightEntry.weight];

    if([y floatValue] > [maxYValue floatValue])
        maxYValue = y;

    if([y floatValue] < [minYValue floatValue])
        minYValue = y;

    //[contentArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", y, @"y",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:goalWeight],@"goalY",nil]];
    [contentArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", y, @"y",nil]];
}
self.dataForPlot = [NSArray arrayWithArray:contentArray];

[minYValues addObject:minYValue];
[maxYValues addObject:maxYValue];


lblHighValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"High = %0.2f", [maxYValue floatValue]];
lblLowValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Low = %0.2f", [minYValue floatValue]];
lblRefrenceValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Goal = %0.2f", self.refereceValue];

   }

       // Update the Plot Space Range to cover all graphs
     - (void) setRangeForGraph{
NSNumber* minimumYValue;
NSNumber* maxmumYValue;

if([minYValues count] > 0 && [maxYValues count] > 0){
    minimumYValue = [minYValues objectAtIndex:0];
    maxmumYValue = [maxYValues objectAtIndex:0];

    // Calculate minimum y value among all graphs.
    for (int i = 0 ; i < [minYValues count] ; i++) {
        if([[minYValues objectAtIndex:i] floatValue] < [minimumYValue floatValue])
            minimumYValue = [minYValues objectAtIndex:i];
    }

    // Calculate maximum y value among all graphs.
    for (int i = 0 ; i < [maxYValues count] ; i++) {
        if([[maxYValues objectAtIndex:i] floatValue] > [maxmumYValue floatValue])
            maxmumYValue = [maxYValues objectAtIndex:i];
    }

    NSDecimalNumber *high = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[maxmumYValue decimalValue]];
    high = [high decimalNumberByAdding:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"30"]];

    // Modify the y range for plot space to cover all values.
    CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:[high decimalValue]];
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPDecimalFromInt([self.dataForPlot count])];

    CPPlotAreaFrame *area = (CPPlotAreaFrame *)graph.plotAreaFrame;
    area.paddingLeft = 20;
    area.paddingBottom = 10;

    CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet*)graph.axisSet;
    //axis.paddingLeft = 20.0;
    axisSet.xAxis.paddingBottom = 50.0;


    CPXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromInteger([self.dataForPlot count]);

    CPXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromFloat([high floatValue]);

    axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromFloat([minimumYValue floatValue]);

        //axisSet.xAxis.labelOffset = 0.0;
    CPLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor colorWithCGColor:((UIColor*)kProtienColor).CGColor];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;

        // style the graph with white text and lines
    CPTextStyle *whiteText = [CPTextStyle textStyle];
    whiteText.color = [CPColor redColor];              


        //CPXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromString(@"1");
    x.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
        //x.majorGridLineStyle=lineStyle;
        //x.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
        //x.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;

    x.title = @"Weight";
    x.titleOffset = 3.0f;
    x.titleLocation = CPDecimalFromFloat(3.0f);

    x.titleTextStyle = whiteText;
    x.labelTextStyle = whiteText;


    //y.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromString(@"150");
    //y.minorTicksPerInterval = 10;
    y.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
    y.title = @"Date";
    y.titleTextStyle = whiteText;
    y.titleOffset = 0;
    y.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
        //y.titleLocation = CPDecimalFromFloat(graph.frame.origin.y+10);
        //y.majorGridLineStyle=lineStyle;
        //y.labelTextStyle=whiteText;

}
   }

   - (NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot {
int nofOfRecords = 0;

@try {

    nofOfRecords = [self.dataForPlot count];
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception while calculating graph index : %@", [e description]);
}
@finally {
    //NSLog(@"Number of Records : %d For Graph Index : %d", nofOfRecords, graphIndex);
    return nofOfRecords;
}
     }

    - (NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
NSNumber *num = 0;
//int plotIndex = [(NSString *)plot.identifier intValue];
if([self.dataForPlot count] > 0){
    if(![((NSString*)[plot identifier]) isEqualToString:kGoalWeightPlot]){
        num = [[dataForPlot objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:(fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y")];
    }else {
        if(fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX)
            num = [[dataForPlot objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"x"];
        else {
            num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.refereceValue];
        }
    }

}
return num;
   }
```

Screenshot -

[image: My Graph]

I want to show custom labels on x-axis and default labels on y-axis.

EDIT:

I've tried adding sample class of barChart+XIB from CPTest-iPhoneApp. The bar chart appears but axis label's don't. Here is the screenshot form CPTest-iPhone app and mine.

[image: CPTest-iPhoneApp]

[image: mine]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem. All I have to do is start adding core-plot from beginning. I removed core-plot from my project again add voila! it's working

Answer (score 0):

```
CPXYAxis *yy = axisSet.yAxis;
yy.axisLineStyle.lineColor=[CPColor whiteColor];
yy.majorTickLineStyle = nil;
yy.minorTickLineStyle = nil;
yy.title = @"Y Axis";
yy.titleLocation = CPDecimalFromFloat(100.0f);
yy.titleOffset = 245.0f;
```

// Define some custom labels for the data elements
    yy.labelingPolicy = CPAxisLabelingPolicyNone;

```
NSArray *customTickLocations1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:10],[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:20], [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:30], nil];

NSArray *yAxisLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b", @"c",nil];

NSUInteger labelLocation1 = 0;
```

NSMutableArray *customLabels1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[yAxisLabels count]];

for (NSNumber *tickLocation1 in customTickLocations1)

```
{
    CPAxisLabel *newLabel1 = [[CPAxisLabel alloc] 

            initWithText: [yAxisLabels objectAtIndex:labelLocation1++] 

            textStyle:yy.labelTextStyle];
```

newLabel1.tickLocation = [tickLocation1 decimalValue];

newLabel1.offset = yy.labelOffset + yy.majorTickLength;

[customLabels1 addObject:newLabel1];

[newLabel1 release];

```
}
yy.axisLabels =  [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels1];
```

Comment: I've already posted image in my post. I am getting all the things except axis labels. I've tried to put sample app of core plot's code as it is in my app, but no luck in getting title labels. See images in my post you will understand what i meant to say