# Core-Plot does not show axes titles

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I'm using Core-Plot to visualize temperature values over time. This works fine with one exception: no titles are shown for the axes, nor are ticks labeled.

Below you will find the code I'm using. I'm using the latest version of CorePlot-CocoaTouch. Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Note: Basically, I'm having the same problem stated in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349307/unable-to-show-anything-on-x-axis-and-y-axis-labels-in-core-plot), but removing/adding CorePlot from/to the project doesn't solve my problem.

**Edit:** I used the latest version from the repository. Changing to 1.0 (the download), it works like a charm.

```
CPTXYGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
graphHostingView.collapsesLayers = NO; 
graphHostingView.hostedGraph     = graph;

graph.paddingLeft   = 10.0;
graph.paddingTop    = 10.0;
graph.paddingRight  = 10.0;
graph.paddingBottom = 10.0;

CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
plotSpace.xRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(500.0)];
plotSpace.yRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(40.0)];

CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;    
CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
x.title = @"Date";
x.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromString(@"280");
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
x.minorTicksPerInterval       = 4;    

CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.title = @"Temperature";
y.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromString(@"10");
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
y.minorTicksPerInterval       = 2;    

CPTScatterPlot *temperaturePlot  = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
temperaturePlot.interpolation = CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved;
temperaturePlot.dataSource    = self;

[graph addPlot:temperaturePlot];
```

**Edit**: Adding padding to the plotArea does not help, as seen in the screenshots below.
[image: Plot without padding]
[image: Plot with padding]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue isn't solved yet and I forwarded it to the official issue list ([core-plot issue](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=448)). For the moment, I switched back to version 1.0 which is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some padding to the plot area frame to make room for the labels.

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft   = 70.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop    = 20.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight  = 20.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 80.0;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. I'll attach two screenshots to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just try by adding labelTextStyle property with some  custom label Text style to your axis. 
`axisSet.xAxis.labelTextStyle = LabelStyle;`
LabelStyle  is an object of `CPTMutableTextStyle`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there are still no visible titles (tried setting a color, size, and even font).